# Weird behavior with Google Cloud PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-9.6

I'm running the Google Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to a remote PostgreSQL (v9.6) instance on Google Cloud (GCP).

I'm having a very weird issue with the number of returned rows from these 2 queries:

```
select "id", "original_image" 
from "tableA" 
where "image_id" is NULL 
order by "id" asc 
limit 581
```

returns **0 rows**

```
select "id", "original_image" 
from "tableA" 
where "image_id" is NULL 
order by "id" asc 
limit 580
```

returns **73 rows**

If I remove the WHERE clause (`where "image_id" is NULL`) both return the limit amount (581 and 580, respectively).

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried running the query on cloud console? Are you getting the same result? What is the result of Select count(*) from tableA where image_id is NULL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Omair. I'm not quite sure what do you mean by cloud console. I don't believe there is a way to make queries on https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/, if that is what you mean.

Comment: What I meant was using the cloud shell option on cloud console.